# ViewController is loaded, but the view doesn't show up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view whose controller is being instantiated (NSLog says so), but the view doesn't show up. If I load it as a modal view it appears, but not if I allocate it.

I have this structure (MenuView is the view that doesn't appear):

// ViewController.h

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
@class MenuViewController;
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>{
    ...
    IBOutlet MenuViewController         *menuView;
}
...
@property(nonatomic, retain) MenuViewController *menuView;
@end
```

// ViewController.m

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize menuView;

- (void)loadMenu{
  // THIS WORKS
  // [self presentModalViewController:menuView animated:YES];

  // THIS DOESN'T (VIEWCONTROLLER IS INSTANTIATED BUT VIEW DOESN'T APPEAR

  menuView = [[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:Nil] autorelease];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:menuView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is anything displaying or just not the view you want?

Comment: The first view (ViewController.xib) is being displayed. The new one that I want (MenuView.xib) is not being displayed

Comment: My guess is that there is no navigation controller, or it's not the controller currently "on top".  (Remember, `pushViewController` will be perfectly silent if `navigationController` is nil.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some ideas:

Try using self.menuView when assigning:

`self.menuView = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:Nil];`

Also, probably shouldn't autorelease a `property`.  Release it in `dealloc` and set it to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`.

---

Make sure that `self (ViewController)` has a `navigationController`.  Was `ViewController` pushed/presented by a `navigationController`?

---

Is `- (void)loadMenu{` being called from the MainThread?  Check with `[NSThread mainThread]`

---

Check out some tutorials/examples:

[Adding a Navigation Controller by Hand](http://davemeehan.com/technology/starting-the-application)

[NavigationController Application in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/navigationcontroller-application-in-iphone/)

[Tutorial: Introducing UINavigationController Part 1](http://www.matthewcasey.co.uk/2010/05/23/tutorial-introducing-uinavigationcontroller-part-1/)

[iPhone View Switching Tutorial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/)

---

Comment: `[self setMenuView:[[[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuView" bundle:nil];` will be less calls. I'm curious to hear your reasoning as to why not to autorelease a property?

Comment: Same result. MenuViewController is instantiated but the old view stays in place. Thanks for the other tips

Comment: @coldlogic I have read several places proper property etiquette but never actually tried autoreleasing a property so everything may work but I believe it is incorrect form.

Comment: Is `- (void)loadMenu{` being called from the MainThread?  Check with if ([NSThread mainThread]) {}

Comment: Oops! No, ViewController is the first view loaded in the app (I started from a "single view application" project). I thought that navigationController was a standard property of self. How should I proceed?

Comment: It still can work.  Just use the Interface Builder (for MainWindow.xib) to add a `Navigation Controller` and make its `View Controller (Root View Controller)` your main `viewController`.

Comment: Or, check out Check out [Adding a Navigation Controller by Hand](http://davemeehan.com/technology/starting-the-application).  This seems to explain exactly what you need.

Comment: It looks like I used the wrong approach. I'll check those tutorials and proceed from there. Thanks!

Comment: @chown: I autorelease all my properties all the time. It works far better than me trying to remember to release stuff in deallocs or remembering to set them to nil in timed methods. But to each his own.

Comment: @ColdLogic -- I don't quite understand.  How can you autorelease a property for an object that you may expect to persist beyond the lifetime of the current autorelease pool?  (Do you declare such properties `retained`?)

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, I retain all my properties. Anything that I do not expect to last beyond the current ARP, I don't make a property, and instead handle the retains and releases in their scope.